# Oracle text single character wildcard does not match whitespace

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracle-text

Lets say you need to find a combination of words

Then using oracle text it would look like:

```
select * from some_table
where contains(column, '%word1 word2%');
```

But what if there could be any other separating character. ".," for example.
then you would go for something like this

```
select * from some_table
where contains(column, '%word1_word2%');
```

eventually it would not work as in oracle text single wildcard "_" does not match white spaces for some reason and as the result you would loose records like:

```
word1 word2
```

Are there any ways to solve this problem?

Comment: I have no idea about contains() function or 12c but maybe you could use OR operator with both the `contains(column, '%word1 word2%') OR contains(column, '%word1_word2%');`

Comment: this could be slow and does not scale

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways you can use to check the results you are searching for.

You can use "LIKE" keyword for searching the words you are interested in. As an example please check the below. You can combine the patterns you are searching with "OR" keyword.

```
select * from some_table where column LIKE '%word1 word2%' OR '%word1_word2%';
```

And also you can use [ORACLE REGEXP_LIKE Condition](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/regexp_like.php) to get the same.

Cheers !!

Comment: I am looking for Oracle Text solution